# Eclipse won't let me select a Windows share as Workspace

Tags: 10.04, 64-bit, samba, android, eclipse

Environment: Ubuntu 10.04 (64-bit), Eclipse Helios 3.6 (64-bit), Android 2.3 SDK + ADT.

All works great, but I can only select a workspace that's on the local system. Eclipse won't let me select shared folder on a Samba server.

Ubuntu's URI for this share is of the form:

```
   smb://userid@192.168.0.2/sandbox/workspace
```

But even if I typed this manually into the edit box, Eclipse won't accept it.

I don't have this problem with Eclipse 3.6 on Windows.

Is there a workaround to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a workaround, without needing to install an additional SMB/CIFS package and/or additional mounts:

The GNOME smb shares are always mounted under the home directory:

```
~/.gvfs/sharename on 192.168.0.2/sandbox/workspace
```

(make sure you select it using the browse button, not typing the full path by hand)

So simple... :)

Comment: For complete dummies: `.gvfs` is a hidden directory; to view it, in the Open File dialog, right click and enable viewing hidden files.

Answer (score 2):

It will help to use CIFS. Does this link help? [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently)?
You'll need the smbfs package to start.

```
sudo apt-get install smbfs
```

Replicated from the Wiki

**Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick Meercat**

Using the text editor of your choice, create a file with your remote servers logon credential. Replace the  with the local username. The following will open up the GEdit application:

```
sudo gedit /home/<LOCALUSERNAME>/.smbcredentials
```

Place your username and password into the file. Replace the  and  with the appropriate information:

```
username=<REMOTEUSERNAME>
password=<REMOTEPASSWORD>
```

Save and exit.

Change the permissions on the file to prevent unwanted eyes from viewing your remote share's logon information:

```
sudo chmod 600 /home/<LOCALUSERNAME>/.smbcredentials
```

Open the file system table file for editing. The following will use GEdit to edit it:

```
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

Add the remote share to the table on a line by itself. The following line when replaced with appropriate data will mount the share for reading and writing:

```
//<SERVERNAME>/<REMOTEPATH> /<LOCALMOUNTPOINT>/<LOCALPATH> cifs credentials=/home/<LOCALUSERNAME>/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

Save and exit.

Finally, test the fstab entry by issuing:

```
sudo mount -a
```

If no errors are output, it is likely safe to test with a reboot.
Your remote share should now mount automatically every boot.

**UPDATE**

It may be that you need be to "map" your username and group to the remote file system's username and group, using `uid=x,gid=y` in /etc/fstab, where x=your_uid and y=your_gid (on the remote server).

```
//<SERVERNAME>/<REMOTEPATH> /<LOCALMOUNTPOINT>/<LOCALPATH> cifs credentials=/home/<LOCALUSERNAME>/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,uid=YOUR_USERID,gid=YOUR_GROUP_ID 0 0
```

Comment: @Christopher this is a great answer (and +1 for that) but I hate redundancy and I don't understand why I need to run **two** Samba clients... If GNOME's Windows share support is incomplete, why include it at all? Why not include CIFS instead?

Comment: @AndroidEve Gosh, I could only guess. I know CIFS supersedes smbfs. Is there even one network file system installed by default? I don't think I know of any. But I know I like it best whenever I use them - nfs, sshfs, cifs.

Comment: @Christopher I eventually gave up and took your advice to use the smbfs package to workaround this problem. Alas, as you can see from the thread below, I still can't use it since I need non-root access. Can you help? Your answer will be the accepted one once it works. :) http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/showthread.php?p=4244709&posted=1#post4244709

Comment: @AndroidEve The share should be mounted using your credentials from /etc/fstab's credentials switch - automatically at boot time. You should be able to write. Do we need to 'chown androideve.androideve /mnt/smb-sambaserv-myshare'?

Comment: @AndroidEve Actually, on my system (10.10), and doing the very same things, the permissions on the directory are automagically changed to my user and group, so I guess that's not it either. The wiki instructions above worked off the bat for me.

Comment: @AndroidEve Stab in the dark: is your user in the fuse group?

Comment: @Christopher Ouch. You caught me again in my ignorance. What is the fuse group? From doing 'grep -i fuse /etc/group' I can see that my user is **not** in fuse group. Also, if you examine more closely the thread that I mentioned, you'll see that I used the credentials properly and I do manage to mount but w/o full read/write. This makes me feel so stupid. I don't ever recall spending so much time on such a seemingly minor issue. What am I missing?

Comment: OMG I think that I have a break through... I just tried **mount.cifs //sambaserv/myshare /mnt/smb-sambaserv-myshare --user=remoteuser** and it mounted (I setuid properly) again with the read/write access problem (as before) but this time I also did **ls -lad /mnt/smb-sambaserv-myshare** and I discovered that the just as you said the owner:group of the mount point changed accordingly but not to the local ones but rather to the **remote** ones, which have **totally different uid/gid**... I think that explains it and now I need to find a way to reconcile the difference. Ideas?

Comment: I think I am getting there... I added to the mount.cifs command the option **-o setuids**. That magically made the local desktop user the owner of that entire mount, including newly created files **while at the same time** those newly created files have the remote user as their owner on the remote system! It looks very promising but it doesn't work yet because if I try to edit a newly such created file, the local system says "Could not open the file... You do not have the permissions necessary to open the file." This is weird since it's -rw- on both systems for both usernames. Ideas?

Comment: BTW, adding the local user to the FUSE group doesn't help.

Comment: @AndroidEve Oh that must be it! I am using a Samba server, and I have a user account on that machine that also has the same username and UID as my workstation user account.

Comment: @AndroidEve Thank you! I have learned another troubleshooting gotcha. The uid/gid mapping is the missing link?

Comment: @Christopher It's too early to celebrate. :) I went through the whole ordeal of creating another user with the **same uid/gid** as the one on the remote server, just to experience the same problem. This time I had no choice, I had to find an explanation for this weird "permission denied" error. So I looked at /var/log. Sure enough, kern.log shows: **Status code returned 0xc0000022 NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED** and **CIFS VFS: Send error in read = -13**. Now I need to understand what this means and why this is happenning.

Comment: I just found a description of the same exact problem (only on a Windows client instead of Ubuntu 10): http://www.fedoraforum.org/forum/showthread.php?t=100193 -- at least I know I'm not imagining this.

Comment: Which led me to find http://www.fedoraforum.org/forum/showpost.php?p=581821&postcount=26 and, sure enough, my server's samba version is **3.0.23a** (please don't ask why I am running such an old version)

Comment: Interestingly enough, this bug never posed any problem on any of my Windows XP, Vista or 7 clients...

Comment: @AndroidEve Does the solution under "UPDATE" (above) fix it?

Answer (score 1):

As you said **smb://userid@192.168.0.2/sandbox/workspace** is a URI much like ftp://somesite.com. URIs need programs which understand the protocol mentioned in the URI i.e smb in case of samba share and ftp in case of FTP. We do not expect Eclipse to use an ftp location as a workspace and in the same manner it may not be able to use an smb location as workspace. If you want to use a windows share as workspace first simply mount it locally using a command similar to following:

```
mount -t smbfs -o username=name,password=password //machinename/sharename /mnt/smbshare
```

Now you you can use use the folder /mnt/smbshare as your workspace. You dont have to mount it to /mnt/smbshare you can mount it any where you want.

Comment: I consider this an Eclipse bug, since forcing me to mount the same share **twice** goes against any design elegance logic... I "solved" the problem by sticking with Windows 7. When either Eclipse or Ubuntu improve in that regard, I will happily consider a switch. +1 for the explanation.